# Index error, csv files

Tags: python, csv

Let's say I have a csv file with this in it:

```
Luke,4
Michael,6
```

If I run this code, it always returns 'IndexError: list index out of range':

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        n = row[0]
        print(n)
```

If I comment out the n = row[0] and change it to `print(row)`, it prints out:

```
['Luke', '4']
['Michael', '5']
[]
```

That extra list is causing the problem but I'm not sure how to get rid of it? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is that you have an empty final line in your csv file.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle empty rows when parsing:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row: # Excluding empty rows here.
            n = row[0]
            print(n)
```